# Does it matter which version of CONCATENATE I use in a given query?

Tags: sql, concatenation

I just learned about CONCAT, CONCATENATE, CONCAT_WS, and CONCAT with + . My understanding is that ultimately each of these CONCAT functions will combine strings into new strings, and that CONCAT will not insert a space, while CONCATENATE, CONCAT_WS, and CONCAT with + could. Does it really matter which one I choose to use?

This is a general learning question, not a question to solve a current issue.

Comment: Use the one that solves your problem. And it varies by DBMS, too. For example, some DBMS will not allow you to `concat` more than 2 columns. In that case you must use `||` in instead of `concat()`.

Comment: The functions will generally handle nulls as empty strings while the operators `+` and `||` will propagate.

Comment: SQL is just a common language used by multiple dbms vendors.  Which dbms are you using???  I'm pretty sure not all of them will work in your dbms.

Comment: It depends on the specific database. Which one are you using?